# Do all automorphisms of $\mathbb{H}$ preserve the norm of an element?

Tags: number-theory, quaternions

Do all automorphisms of $\mathbb{H}$-- the Hamilton quaternions-- preserve the norm of an element? I can't seem to answer this question without using the not-so-elementary fact that all automorphisms of $\mathbb{H}$ are inner-- this tells us that all automorphisms fix $\mathbb{R}$, and so for any given $x=a+bi+cj+dk$, $\phi(x)=a+b\phi(i) + c \phi(j)+d \phi(k)$. Am I making some blatantly incorrect assumption? If so, how would I show this fact about the norm being preserved?

Comment: Just define which structures must an “automorphism” preserve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note than any ($\mathbb{R}$-algebra) automorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{H}$ preserves $1$ and hence (pointwise) $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, any automorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{H}$ is given by $\phi(x) := q x q^{-1}$ for some $q \in \mathbb{H}^*$. We may as well pull out the norm of $q$ and absorb it into its inverse, and so assume that $q$ and $q^{-1}$ both have unit length, and in particular that $\phi(x) = q x \bar{q}$.

We show now that any automorphism $\phi$ preserves the squared norm $Q(x) := |x|^2 = x \bar{x}$ of an arbitrary element $x \in \mathbb{H}$:

$Q(\phi(x)) = Q(qx\bar{q}) = qx\bar{q}\overline{qx\bar{q}} = qx\bar{q}q\bar{x}\bar{q}$.

Now, $\bar{q}q = 1$, so this is

$qx\bar{x}\bar{q} = q Q(x) \bar{q} = Q(x) q\bar{q} = Q(x)$,

where the middle equality uses that $Q(x)$ is real.

**Remark** The fact that any automorphism of $\mathbb{H}$ preserves the norm (or quadratic form $Q$) corresponds to the inclusion $Aut(\mathbb{H}) \cong SU(2) \hookrightarrow SO(4) \cong SO(Q)$. In particular the action of $SU(2)$ preserves the orthocomplement $\mathbb{R}^{\perp} \cong \mathbb{R}^3$ and the restriction of $Q$ to that set and so it defines a homomorphism $SU(2) \to SO(3)$; it turns out to be surjective and have kernel $\{\pm 1\}$, and so it is a double cover.

**Remark 2** Note that we can in fact prove that the algebraic structure and norm are compatible in a stronger sense yet, namely that they satisfy $Q(x y) = Q(x) Q(y)$.

Thanks to Jyrki Lahtonen for pointing out an issue with a previous argument.

Comment: How do you express quaternion conjugation with ring operations?

Comment: But how would I see that the norm is fixed by automorphisms in an elementary way, and without using this fact about the inner product?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I've edited the post to include the identity. NB that no such formula can exist for $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Travis: It often happens that $\phi(i)\neq i$ (ditto with $j$ and $k$), so I still don't see how you deduce that $\overline{\phi(y)}=\phi(\overline{y})$. Isn't that needed for your argument?

Comment: @user151882 I've edited my post to make more explicit that you can view this as a fact about the norm the inner product induces. If you wanted to show this directly, you could simply show that for an arbitrary automorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{H}$ that $|\phi(q)| = |q|$ for arbitrary $q$. You can compute this in components, for example. But you might well regard the above formula for $\bar{y}$ as more elementary than the fact that all automorphisms are inner, in which case the proof I suggested is "easier".

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen One can rewrite the right-hand side using an arbitrary orthogonal basis of $\Im \mathbb{H}$ instead of $(i, j, k)$, and $\phi$ takes any such basis to another and so preserves this expression.

Comment: In other words, you assume that $\phi$ preserves the norm to prove that it does so. Wonderfully circular.

Comment: @Travis How would I compute this in components without assuming that automorphisms of $\mathbb{H}$ fix $\mathbb{R}$/ how would I show that automorphisms fix $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you, I take your point, but there's no need for sarcasm.

Comment: @user151882 Any $\mathbb{R}$-algebra automorphism $\phi$ must fix $1$ and hence $\mathbb{R}$: For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $q \in \mathbb{H}$, we have $\phi(q) = \phi(1 \cdot q) = \phi(1) \phi(q)$. I'll update my answer in a moment with an explicit argument of the sort you're looking for.

Comment: @Travis An explicit argument would be wonderful, thanks!

Comment: @Travis Why explicitly, does preserving 1 imply preserving $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Because you can "pull constants out of homomorphisms": More precisely, for any algebras $A, B$ over a field (or ring) $\mathbb{K}$, a $\mathbb{F}$-algebra homomorphism $A \to B$ satisfies $F(k a) = k F(a)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{F}$ and $a \in A$, in other words, it's built into the definition.